# Отправка данных на сторонний сервер с авторизацией

Tags: jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток!

Мне нужно отправлять данные на сторонний сервер, на котором происходит авторизация. Информацию про авторизацию нашел на сайте api.jquery.com и больше нигде, но и там всего два слова про это написано. В общем, попробовал сделать так:

function send_secret(phone) {

```
                  secret =  $("#secret_code").val();

                  $.ajax({
                      username:'some_user',
                      password:'some_password',
                      url:'http://some_server/index.php',
                      type:'POST',
                      data:'code=' + secret + '&phone=' + phone,
                      success: function(res) {
                           alert('Success');
                          $('#wrapper').html(res);
                      }
                  });
                  return false;

          }
```

Но ответа так и не пришло. Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Заранее спасибо за советы!

Comment: А сторонний сервер про вас знает? Присылает вам хедеры CORS?

Comment: Кроссдоменные запросы запрещены, пока CORS этого не разрешает.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но с технологией cors не знаком. Можете уточнить, а этот заголовок должен мне сторонний сервер присылать до отправки или после отправки мною данных? Да, сторонний сервер про меня знает.

Comment: @тигрище, в ответе на ваш запрос сервер должен прислать разрешающие cors заголовки для вашего домена (или для всех?), просто наберите это слово в гугле, он даст полную картину для знакомства, там всё очень-очень просто.

Comment: [Тут](http://cors.kojo.ru/) от профи Яндекса несколько полезных ссылок про CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть один вариант... так как посредством JS не всегда можно корректно выполнить запрос (и получить ответ) на сторонний сервер, то можно выполнить AJAX на свой сервер, и с сервера через curl или элементарно через file_get_contents выполнить запрос на другой сервер и в JS вернуть результат. Если необходимо, то можно сразу же у себя установить куку и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо ) Почитал разных материалов и решил попробовать ваш вариант )